# Imprimir uma pagina php em uma impressora especifica

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema php que preciso imprimir uma pagina em uma impressora especifica ,meu computador tem varias impressora como eu posso fazer isso,alguma outra linguagem que posso usar com o php para realizar esse processo ??

Comment: É impossível, isso não é feito no PHP, PHP está no servidor e não na máquina do usuário ... o que faz imprimir é o front-end, no caso JavaScript, mas JavaScript é limitado para isto, você só dispõe do `window.print();`, é provável que nunca liberem um recurso assim em JS pois isso implicaria em segurança do usuário/equipamento.

Comment: tem alguma maneira de implementar outra linguagem no php ou plugin qualquer coisa que me ajude a escolher uma impressora especifica .

Comment: Não, é impossível, antigamente existia Applets (escrito em Java), mas esse tipo de recurso controla o equipamento do usuário, isso é totalmente inseguro, por isso os navegadores modernos removeram suporte para Applets. Note que mesmo mudando de linguagem sobre o PHP, não vai funcionar, a questão não é um problema no PHP, a questão é CLIENTE e SERVIDOR, se o servidor pudesse controlar a máquina do usuário (tipo selecionar uma impressora desejada) isso poderia ser usado para o MAL e teríamos vários ataques, usar a internet seria impossível.

Comment: Não tem, tem que escolher a tecnologia certa para resolver o problema que tem. Navegadores não servem para esta necessidade e PHP essencialmente só trabalha fornecendo páginas para eles. Quase todas aplicações no mundo deveriam ser nativas por inúmeras razões, mas por alguma razão as pessoas acham que tudo pode ser resolvido pela web, quando na verdade ela só soluciona uma coisa, a pessoa não precisar instalar nada na máquina dela, obviamente aceitando todas as desvantagens que isto traz.